# moving image behind label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image on my view, which I add programmatically & and not through storyboards. The image gets animated to move up the screen. At one point it crosses paths with several buttons and labels, which contain important text that gets blocked by the image passing over them. I want the image to move under the labels and buttons so that the text remains visible. Based on this answer [IPhone Interface Builder: Z-Index, Z-order of a button, image, ui element, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276116/iphone-interface-builder-z-index-z-order-of-a-button-image-ui-element-etc), I tried to use editor => arrange => sendToBack/sendToFront, however, I don't think this is having any effect because the image doesn't appear in the tree of elements in the storyboard.   As noted, it gets added programmatically at a certain time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519141/difference-between-addsubview-and-insertsubview-in-uiview-class?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @cyborg86pl yes it did thanks if you add it as an answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll add it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in answer to this question: [Difference between addSubview and insertSubview in UIView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519141/difference-between-addsubview-and-insertsubview-in-uiview-class?answertab=active#tab-top)

If you're using `addSubview:`, your view will be placed on top. To control it's depth use either `insertSubview:atIndex:` (at exact place from bottom) or `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` or `insertSubview:belowSubview:` (which places new view above/below another known object in view hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `[view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]` which will place it behind all other subviews. Depending on what other subviews you have, you may need to increase the `index` as it controls what is placed over what in the view (lower `index` will go behind higher `index`)