# How to port an iPad app to Mac?

Tags: iphone, ipad, macos, port

I know [it's not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579849/port-an-ios-iphone-app-to-mac). Is there a step-by-step guide for iOS developer to climb the Mac OS learning curve?

Besides, IconFactory is working on the [chameleon project](http://chameleonproject.org/). How much effort will be saved comparing to a traditional port?

Comment: One thing that **is** easy? Memory management. GC is there all for your taking! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a similar learning curve to learning iOS SDK development, minus the stuff that's the same: tools, cocoa conventions, Foundation objects (NSString NSArray etc), Core Graphics & Core Animation (mostly), and other lower level frameworks that are similar in both. Basically everything in your app that uses `UI<something>` needs to be rewritten in something similar but different. In many apps that's a big percentage. I myself eagerly await this "cha-me-leon" project (yes, that's a HIMYM reference).