# Is Swift a solution to "porting iOS app to OSX"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, porting

I've read a bit about Swift and it seems to be a lot easier to draw using Swift. When porting an iOS app to OS X there's the issue of nested `UIView`'s not working the same way in OS X, and that you have to use `CALayer`s a lot instead of `NSView`s. Is Swift a solution to this issue? Can Swift help me to draw content for OS X that originates from iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Swift is just another language. It's a different syntax, but Cocoa and UIKit itself don't change. Swift can't help you drawing something easier.

Swift also has absolutely nothing to do with porting apps.

Comment: IMO with Swift one has to type *more* cryptic things.

Comment: Agreed. Swift seems more cryptic to me too.

Comment: Yes! More cryptic - but everybody claims it's more readable. I will miss objective c in the (far) future :(

Comment: I must say that I haven't used Swift myself and just repeated what most people claim.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not.

Porting from iOS to OSX is discussed briefly in this question:
[port an iOS (iPhone) app to mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579849/port-an-ios-iphone-app-to-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Swift is just a language. 
Nothing special in it for porting. 
UIKit views have Core Animation baked in basically. 
AppKit added CALayers after years of them not even being a concept. 
The two APIs are different but not so different that it should matter much or be too difficult.