# Port an iOS app to OSX (mac)?

Tags: ios, macos

There are already some questions regarding this topic at SO, but they are quite old, so I wanted to know if nowadays there is something that allows to port an iOS app (swift & objective-c) to OSX.

If the answer is no, Is it "easy" to do this task for one with no experience in OSX programming ?

Comment: What's wrong with the old questions? Nothing has changed.

Comment: Should be pretty simple as there is very little difference between OSX and iOS (except for the UI) but it depends on the application's code. Please provide more information about the technologies you are using and post links to all the old questions.

Comment: Absolute unmitigated duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579849/port-an-ios-iphone-app-to-mac. Someone please hammer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it "easy" to do this task for one with no experience in OSX programming

No. Desktop programming is nothing like iOS programming. Cocoa Touch (on iOS) is a very different framework from good old-fashioned decades-old crufty tricky complex Cocoa. What you describe is do-able, but it can't be done by magic or by machine; it requires serious human work, and to call that work "easy" is wrong. There's a definite non-trivial learning curve.