# NSScrollview and transparent, overlay NSScroller subclasses

Tags: cocoa, transparency, drawrect, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I have made a slick `NSScroller` subclass, but can't figure out how to make it overlay on top of the `NSScrollView` instead of pushing the `documentView` aside.

[image]

Here you can see the background of a `NSCollectionView` that I wish to make 100% wide, and have the scroller sit along top. Currently, I have to set a white background to the scroller because drawing with a `clearColor` is not showing as transparent, but as black.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Am I missing something obvious here? How can I achieve the behavior of a transparent-tracked `NSScroller` that sits atop a `NSScrollView`'s contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get the positioning by implementing `tile` in the subclass **OF NSSCROLLVIEW**

```
- (void)tile {
    [super tile];
    [[self contentView] setFrame:[self bounds]];
}
```

And it turns out that trying to draw clear color was the problem to begin with. In the scroller subclass, I just omitted any drawing that had to do with the slider track completely **BY OVERRIDING `DRAWRECT:` OF THE NSSCROLLER SUBCLASS, LIKE SO:**

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [self drawKnob];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about getting rid of the drawing that had to do with the track!  I was trying to set it to a clear color but it was messing everything up.  Removed it and all's good!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for this to work properly, you MUST enable layer-backing for the scrollView!

That is, call:

```
[scrollViewInstance setWantsLayer:YES];
```

or set it in Interface Builder.

If you don't do this, the scrollView's contentView will draw ON TOP OF the scrollers. Also: you should be aware that what you're doing is essentially overlapping two NSViews (NSScroller on top of NSScrollView --- both inherit from NSView.) Unlike UIViews on iOS, overlapping NSViews on OS X is not officially supported by any current version of the OS (10.6 down). Turning on CALayers seems to make it work, but it's still something to bear in mind. Of course, turning on layers can seriously kill drawing performance.

See this SO question for more detail: [Is there a proper way to handle overlapping NSView siblings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466297/is-there-a-proper-way-to-handle-overlapping-nsview-siblings)

Comment: This fixed an odd problem I was having with my own transparent scrollbar: it would sometimes flash white when it first appeared, then draw correctly a second or two later.

Answer (score -2):

What's about this color: `[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0]`
I think you have to modify the sizes with the interface builder.

Comment: clearColor is the same. The problem is not in the sizes, but the behavior of NSScroller. The standard behavior is to push the content to the side and draw the bar, I want the content to not be pushed aside, and the bar to draw on top.