# NSImageView drawing incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimageview

I created a custom subclass of NSView in order to control 2 NSImageViews. The code for creating the images is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect AndMap:(NSImage *)map AndPlayer:(NSImage *)guyImage
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self)
    {
        NSRect newRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 64.0, 64.0);

        NSImageView *theMap = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, frameRect.size.width, frameRect.size.height)];
        [theMap setImage:map];

        NSImageView *theGuy = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newRect];
        [theGuy setImage:guyImage];

        [self setMapImage:theMap];
        [self setPlayerView:theGuy];
        [self addSubview:[self mapImage]];
        [self addSubview:[self playerView]];
```

However, when I tell the view to draw in a rect with origin (128,0), it draws *theMap* with a weird offsets, so that *theGuy*'s origin is at 128,0, but *theMap*'s origin is at something like (128,20). I can't find any reason why this should occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have overlapping sibling views:

- `theMap` has frame `{{0.0, 0.0}, {frameRect.size.width, frameRect.size.height}}`
- `theGuy` has frame `{{0.0, 0.0}, {64.0, 64.0}}`
- both `theMap` and `theGuy` are (or seem to be) added to the same superview, namely `self`, and have the same origin.

Cocoa doesn’t guarantee correct behaviour for overlapping sibling views, i.e., two views that have the same direct superview and whose corresponding frames overlap. From the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW1):

> **Note:** For performance reasons, Cocoa does not enforce clipping among sibling views or guarantee correct invalidation and drawing behavior when sibling views overlap. If you want a view to be drawn in front of another view, you should make the front view a subview (or descendant) of the rear view.

According to [this answer to another question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466297/is-there-a-proper-way-to-handle-overlapping-nsview-siblings/466563#466563), one alternative solution is to turn on layers for the views.

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought - are the strange map offsets not accidentally part of the map `NSImage`?