# addSubview not displayed until windows focus has been lost and recovered

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have the following code attached to an `NSButton`

```
- (IBAction) onTest: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"OnTest");
    [overlayView setFrame: scrollView.frame];
    [scrollView.superview addSubview: overlayView];
}
```

My nib is setup as the following picture:

[image: nib setup]

The scrollView outlet is attached to the `NSScrollView` that encloses a `NSTableView` and the overlayView is attached to a `NSView` that has a green background.

On the click of a button, I receive the `OnTest` log message in xcode, but the green view is not visible, however if I switch focus from the applications window to say XCode, then back to the window, the green overlay is now visible.

I've tried using `[scrollView.superView setNeedsDisplay: YES]`, but that still does not cause the green view to be displayed.

Any suggestions as to that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try calling the setNeedsDisplay: of the overlay view instead?
Also who is scrollView.superview?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `setNeedsDisplay:` on both views. `scrollView.superView` would be the main view of the window. "The view instances enclosed within a view are called subviews. The parent view that encloses a view is referred to as its superview" (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html)

Comment: Did you turn on layers for the views? Overlapping sibling views that don't have layers don't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466297/is-there-a-proper-way-to-handle-overlapping-nsview-siblings